# How to handle uploading and downloading CSV files generated by PHP

Tags: php, linux

I am running the following code (slightly abbreviated) to render a MySQL query on screen and store each row to a csv stored in /tmp/

```
$fileName = $username . date('Ymdhis') . '.csv';
$fp = fopen('/tmp/' . $fileName, 'w');

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        if ($count % 2 == 0)
                {
                echo "blah";
                fputcsv($fp, $row);
                $count++;
                }
        else
                {
                echo "blah 2";
                fputcsv($fp, $row);
                $count++;
                }


        }
fclose($fp);
```

Works fine, no complaints.  Now that the file is stored in /tmp, I would like to create an html link to it so that it can be downloaded from the same page.  I know enough to keep the .csv out of the www document root, but what is the most secure way to retrieve this file from /tmp?  Should I set up a symlink from www to /tmp?  How best to approach?

Comment: Ok, a few questions: Why don't you output the file directly to the browser? Is the file to be downloaded multiple times? Is the content of the generated file confidential? How long after creating must the file be available on the server?

Comment: It is already being output to the browser, but more than a couple of people have requested a downloadable version.  The file should not be made available at all to anyone but the person generating it.  The file can be deleted once with 30 minutes after it's generated.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you symlink the file from the document root to `/tmp`, you can as well put it into the docroot directly.

If you say that the file is confidential, but must be downloadable, you can do the following:

Store the file with a very long and random file name (like pvYLLHuGmnJnQ3LBkanQky8oh6eUkhH.csv) in a directory outside the document root.

Create some sort of “dispatcher”: This would basically be a PHP file which takes a request, validates it (be sure to remove any illegal characters, especially dots and slashes!) and returns the file, if it exists.

Then find a way to tell the legitimate user the file name. This may be done by returning that name (or the download URL) instead of the file content as result of the PHP request. Or e.g. by e-mail.

This is of course a rather simple approach, but it should be secure enough for most scenarios. By the way, make sure to use HTTPS for transport, otherwise all this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where would be a good place to put this new directory?  Under /var?

Comment: Woah, that's a big question. ;) Depends on your partitioning, data management strategy, security model etc. … But if the files are to be deleted after some time, I'd recommend staying in a subdirectory of `/tmp` – and create a cron job which removes old files after a while, so they don't clutter the FS.